# WebAPI - Passing JSON of derived class

Tags: jquery, angularjs, entity-framework, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI,Entity Framework, and AngularJS and am trying to serialize a derived class type in a kendo grid and send this to a WebAPI method. I have the follow model association:

```
class FREQ_POOL<---- Base class
class POOL_FAA:FREQ_POOL<----derived class
class FREQUENCY(Contains a FREQ_POOL object)
```

I am using a kendo ui with a model as follows:

```
model: {

                        id: "Id",
                        fields: { 
                            Frequency: { type: "string" },

                            FREQ_POOL: {
                                $type: 'DomainModelModule.POOL_FAA, DomainModelModule',
                               // type: "object",
                                defaultValue: {}
                            } 
                        }
                    }
....
 $("#FAAFreqGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: FAADS,

            columns: [ 
            { field: "Frequency", editor: categoryDropDownEditor, title: "Frequency Test", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                 { field: "FREQ_POOL.FAADesignator", title: "FAA Designator", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
```

FAADesignator belongs to the derived class POOL_FAA. This works 100% fine when I have a manually created row in my db. It is the creation part in code that is not working.

I am using the right typename handling in my web api config based on what I have read:

```
  var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;


         json.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto; //THIS IS NEEDED FOR CASTING
        json.SerializerSettings.TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Now I still am unable to cast my FREQ_POOL to a POOL_FAA in my WebAPI method:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(FREQUENCY))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostFREQUENCY([FromBody]FREQUENCY testfreq)
    {

        FREQUENCY ftest = new FREQUENCY();
        ftest.FREQ_POOL = new POOL_FAA();             
        POOL_FAA sdgsdg = (POOL_FAA)ftest.FREQ_POOL;//WORKS WHEN MANUALLY CREATED

        POOL_FAA pool = (POOL_FAA)testfreq.FREQ_POOL;//THROWS EXCEPTION
    }
```

As you saw, I used $type to establish the type it should cast to, but that does not seem to be working.

I noticed that $type is not appearing in my stringified json:

```
{"Id":0,"Frequency":"","FREQ_POOL":{"FAADesignator":"sdfgsfdg","DateFilled":"dfg","DueDate":"fhg","Released":"sdfh","ReleasedDate":"dsfh","Comments":"sdfh"},
```

But I am including it so I don't know why it would be excluding it. This is my best guess as to why it isn't working. I am using Angular and Kendo, and since my variable is inside a kendo Model I thought that might be excluding $type or something.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I switched from model-first to code-first, I didn't explicitly use TPT inheritance. After switching to TPT from TPH inheritance everything was solved.